# Requisição HTTP dentro de uma empresa que utiliza proxy

Tags: vba, http-request, proxy

Desculpa se essa pergunta é repetida. Eu sempre tento buscar a resposta antes de perguntar aqui, e dessa vez não achei (de repente não usei as palavras chaves corretas, talvez por falta de conhecimento, mas whatever).

**CONTEXTO**

Trabalho em uma empresa onde possuo acesso restrito à internet. Para acessar alguns sites, é utilizado proxy.

Nessa empresa, de vez em quando eu crio pequenos softwares para automatizar algumas demandas. E para algumas dessas demandas, é necessário acessar sites específicos.

Utilizo muito VBA para fazer isso, uma vez que quem tira proveito desses pedem um relatório do que foi feito, e fazer o software no Excel é bem conveniente.

Para esses softwares que acessam sites, eu geralmente utilizava o VBA para controlar o Internet Explorer, para que ele reproduza as ações necessárias. Nunca gostei de fazer isso, uma vez que alguns sites carregavam conteúdo sem fazer o navegador mostrar que estava ocupado.

Recentemente venho estudando a biblioteca WinHTTP, onde eu posso fazer requisições diretamente ao site que eu quero e recebo o HTML da página, e achei BEM melhor do que usar o Internet Explorer.

Já fiz 2 programas que funcionaram perfeitamente. O primeiro acessava um site **disponível apenas na intranet da empresa**.
O segundo acessava um site externo, e tive que deixar explícito o Proxy ao objeto WinHTTP. Dessa forma, funcionou normal.

**PROBLEMA**

O terceiro programa está sendo problemático. Ele tem que acessar um site externo também, porém mesmo com proxy eu não recebo a página HTML. O pedido me retorna o erro 407 (autenticação do proxy necessária).

Como que no segundo programa que foi feito, não foi pedido essa autenticação?

Tentei utilizar o comando `.SetCredentials` com o meu usuário e senha, mas nada acontece.

Lembro que a resposta possui os cabeçalhos:
"Proxy-Authenticate": "Negotiate"
"Proxy-Authenticate": "Kerberos"
"Proxy-Authenticate": "NTLM"

Tentei também fazer o mesmo pedido de fora da empresa (de casa), e recebi a página html normalmente, com o status 200.

Como proceder para que o programa funcione dentro da empresa?

Answer (score 1):

```
With Teste
.Open "POST", "URL", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"

.setProxy 2, "PROXYAUTENTICACAO:8080" 'colocar o proxy
.setProxyCredentials "SUACREDENCIAL", "SUASENHA" 

End With
```